# Modify Spree Cart.js to Show Correct Cart Item Count and Amount

Tags: javascript, spree, solidus

[spree cart link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZgiZ.png)

This cart shows 3 items from 3 separate order numbers.

But link item number and amount are incorrect because Spree Cart is retrieving data line items for ONE Order from cart.js

I want to be able to return item count and amount from multiple orders.

```
<script>Spree.fetch_cart('<%= j spree.cart_link_path %>')</script>


cart.js
Spree.ready(function($) {
  if ($("form#update-cart").is("*")) {
    $("form#update-cart a.delete")
      .show()
      .one("click", function() {
        $(this)
          .parents(".line-item")
          .first()
          .find("input.line_item_quantity")
          .val(0);
        $(this)
          .parents("form")
          .first()
          .submit();
        return false;
      });
  }
  $("form#update-cart").submit(function() {
    $("form#update-cart #update-button").attr("disabled", true);
  });
});

Spree.fetch_cart = function(cartLinkUrl) {
  Spree.ajax({
    url: cartLinkUrl || Spree.pathFor("cart_link"),
    success: function(data) {
      $("#link-to-cart").html(data);
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Was fixed mod to link_to_cart.